# How should the View pull on the Presenter in the MVP pattern

Tags: asp.net, mvp

I have a ASP.NET Web Forms application and I'm using some dynamic controls in the view which depend on stuff that the presenter exposes. Is it okay for the view in this case to pull on the presenter for that data? Is there anything I should be extra careful about when considering testability and a loosely coupled design.

The page in this case has it's own page-life cycle and the presenter doesn't know about this. However, the page-life cycle dictates that somethings must occur at specific moments in the page-life cycle. This smells like trouble... Any known pit falls?

## EDIT

When my concrete view hits the Init event it will pull on the presenter for a collection that will result in a bunch of ASP.NET server controls to be created. I'm wondering if this is a particular bad thing to do... The presenter doesn't know how to respond to the page-life cycle init event but it has to if the view is to be populated with dynamic controls.

Comment: I'm still not clear on why the presenter needs to be aware of the page life cycle.  Isn't the presenter just giving a collection to the view?  Aren't the server controls created and rendered in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a vexing question - when you want dynamic controls in ASP.NET web forms you've got to choose the lesser of two evils. Ultimately, it comes down to which compromise you want to make: presenter concerns in the view or view concerns in the presenter.

When I work in web forms I usually prefer the latter - I accept that the presenter is tied to the ASP.NET page lifecycle and create an `InitializeView` method to do whatever's necessary to create dynamic controls:

```
// Presenter
// This could also be parameterless if you prefer that idiom but 
// then the view needs a SelectedState property that serves up values
// straight from the Form collection, and it won't be obvious why.
public void InitializeView(string selectedState) { 
    if (selectedState != null) {
        view.Counties = dataLayer.GetCounties(selectedState);
    }
}

// View
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    presenter.InitializeView(Request.Form["StateList"]);
    // ... build counties drop-down ...
}
```

Of course, this ties the presenter's semantics to the ASP.NET lifecycle and obscures what's going on in that method. You can mitigate that by giving `InitializeView` a more descriptive name, like `ProcessSelectedState`, but unless the method name references the page lifecycle, it's never going to be obvious why you're not just getting counties with the rest of the model (in `presenter.LoadModel` or whatever you might call it).

I can see how the alternative is attractive:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    if (Request.Form["StateList"] != null) {
        List<string> counties = presenter.GetCounties(Request.Form["StateList"]);
        // ... build counties drop-down ...
    }
}
```

The semantics of the `Presenter` are perfectly clear -  it's easy to understand what `GetCounties` does and it doesn't have anything to do with the page lifecycle. But you have testable stuff in your view, which is a bummer, and that's usually more important to me than keeping my presenters ignorant of their view engine.

Another alternative is to just load your *entire* model during page initialization. Your server control values won't be available, so you'd have to get any of those from `Request.Form`. That's not idiomatic ASP.NET classic though - it might be unduly confusing since most web forms developers are accustomed to getting values directly from web controls instead of directly from the POST data.

Comment: Thank you for a very insightful answer, to bad I can't give you several thumbs up. It seems to me that's there's not right or wrong it's gonna boil down to what's testable and those important to have properties.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the presenter is where the view is supposed to get it's data from/bind to/etc.  The presenter is the piece that would be unit tested.  From your second statement it sounds like you may need multiple presenters for this page, but I would need more details to be sure.